# segmentation fault when attempting to start psql on Heroku with OSX Snow Leopard (10.6.8)

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to use Postgresql with Heroku.  I installed Postgres 9.1.4 using the installer downloaded from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload.  Then in my `/etc/profile` I added the location of `psql` to my `PATH`.  When I attempt to use the `psql` shell with Heroku I get a segmentation fault but it seems to work fine when I try to use it locally:

```
[Sun Aug 05 20:17:47] : which psql
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql
[Sun Aug 05 20:22:15] : heroku pg:psql
psql (9.1.4)
Segmentation fault
[Sun Aug 05 20:22:21] : psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q
[Sun Aug 05 20:22:29] : heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.30.2 (universal-darwin10.0) ruby/1.8.7
```

I did notice that `heroku version` shows `ruby/1.8.7` but I am using `rvm use 1.9.3`.  Could this Ruby mismatch be the problem?  If so, how do I fix it?  I am not sure what to do next since the segmentation fault error message was pretty vague.  This is all on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: I think that problems like these are why Heroku came out with Postgres.app - http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: @Qsario, thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately it seems like Postgres.app requires Lion (10.7) so I can't try it on my machine since I am still on Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Heroku support and they suggested installing Postgres via Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).  I did this and now I can access my Heroku databases.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem too: `psql` works locally, but segfaults with `heroku pg:psql`. I found that downgrading to Postgres 9.1.3 ([installer still available](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-913-installers-osx&ls=Crossover&type=Crossover)) solved it.

It looks like the `heroku pg:psql` command just calls `psql` with appropriate command line arguments and somehow passes the password in. I can reproduce the problem without the `heroku` command like this:

```
psql -U random_username -h ec2-10-10-10-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 5432 random_dbname
Password for user random_username: 
psql (9.1.4)
Segmentation fault
```

So it appears the problem lies in the `psql` binary. I looked at the stack trace of the core dump, and it appears the problem is something in the SSL processing (which Heroku uses, but isn't usually used with a connection to localhost):

```
#0  0x00000001000da622 in SSL_get_current_cipher ()
#1  0x0000000100007415 in printSSLInfo ()
#2  0x00000001000073c6 in connection_warnings ()
#3  0x00000001000141dd in main ()
```

This makes sense because a successful `psql` connection to Heroku does spit out a line about the SSL cipher connection:

```
heroku pg:psql --app wattdepot-kukuicup-uhm-staging
psql (9.1.3, server 9.1.4)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

random_dbname=>
```

I haven't investigated any further than that.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same problem. On Heroku's advice I just updated from postgres 9.1.4 to 9.1.5 and now "heroku pg:psql" works fine.

Answer (score 1):

We definitely just defer to the psql command with arguments as has been mentioned, so I don't really think anything is really wrong on the Heroku side.  It seems to be that there was a bug in psql that evidently got fixed, so I think updating your local postgres should probably do the trick (it seems to have fixed things for everyone I've talked to about it so far anyway.